# SSRS open URL in new window Javascript function not working with dynamic URL string

Tags: javascript, url, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using `javascript:void(window.open('" & URL & "','_blank'))` to open a URL in a new window. I've used this many times and it works perfectly except when the URL string is built using dynamic parameter values.

**What Works :**

The URL I am trying to open on SSRS action is below:

`SSRSserveraddress/Headcount.rdl&pBusinessUnit=" & Fields!BusinessUnit.Value & "&pCalendar=" & **Code.URLEncode**("[Monthly Calendar].[Monthly Calendar].[Month].&[" & Fields!MonthYear.Value &"])`

The SSRS Action (Go To URL) expression works when using the above URL. It uses the custom Code.URLEncode (see description below) and passes the calendar parameter correctly.

**What does not work:**

The problem is I need this URL to open in a new window. Here's the Javascript action I am using:

`javascript:void(window.open('"SSRSserveraddress/Headcount.rdl&pBusinessUnit=" & Fields!BusinessUnit.Value & "&pCalendar=" & Code.URLEncode("[Monthly Calendar].[Monthly Calendar].[Month].&[" & Fields!MonthYear.Value &"]") 
& "','_blank'))`

I get the following error when using the javascript function above:

`The item 'SSRSServeraddress/Headcount.rdl,[January 2016]' cannot be found`

**Additional information:**

Interestingly, if I don't call the Code.URLEncode function the javascript function above works properly.

So this works:

`javascript:void(window.open('"SSRSserveraddress/Headcount.rdl&pBusinessUnit=" & Fields!BusinessUnit.Value & "','_blank'))`

Code.URLEncode Function is custom code within my report. The goal of this function is to parse any special characters ( %, [, etc) and convert them into unicode value instead so SSRS URL access works.

```
Public Function URLEncode (ByVal inURL As String) As String
Dim outURL As String
outURL = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(inURL).ToString
Return outURL
End Function
```

I'm really stuck and out of ideas of how to fix this issue... Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using ReportViewer Control or how you call this report?

Comment: I am calling this report through a text box within a matrix in another SSRS report.It's an SSRS action. Hope that helps?

Comment: Okay got that, why don't you copy shortcut of that link and check is it correct URL or not? Please let me know what is the URL